# Multiple post types or single post type with category taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, seo

I am thinking what would be the best approach to this situation. Forgive me if I have used terms erroneously. I can either have multiple custom post types which would display individually on the menu and the url would display as such:

domain.com/custom_post_type/article

```
    function art_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Art',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'art','with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'slug',
            'permalink',
            'thumbnail',
            )

        );

    register_post_type( 'art', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'art_init' );


function music_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Music',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'music','with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-album',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'slug',
            'permalink',
            'thumbnail'
            )

        );

    register_post_type( 'music', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'music_init' );
```

Or I could make one custom post type and provide it with a taxonomy that was hierarchical, category like so the url would be:

domain.com/custom_post_type/taxonomy/article

```
    function article_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Articles',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'article/%article_category%','with_front' => true),
        'with_front' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-quote',
        'supports' => array(
            // 'title',
            // 'editor',
            // 'custom-fields'
            )

        );

    register_post_type( 'article', $args );

}

    add_action( 'init', 'article_init' );

    function articleCategory_init() {
       $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Article Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Article Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Article Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Article Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Article Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Article Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Article Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Article Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Article Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Article Category' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Article Categories' ),

      );

      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles', 'with_front' => true),

      );

      register_taxonomy( 'article_category', 'article', $args );

    }
```

Which would work best in consideration of WordPress efficiency and SEO?

Comment: This question is a little vague and ambiguous, what would these custom post types or taxonomies be? I don't see why a search engine would interpret either of them differently

Comment: I did have trouble trying to explain it, however I have attached the code for each implementation which might make it a little clearer.